# C++ cannot allocate too big array of objects on a heap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, heap-memory

I have following c++ code (build on Visual Studio 2013) :

```
MapGraph& MapGraph::operator= (const MapGraph& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        this->primaryCopy = false;

        this->edges = new int[other.edgeQty];
        this->pointers = new int[other.vertexQty + 1];
        this->contents = new int[other.vertexQty]();
        this->weights = new NodeWeight[other.vertexQty];
```

The arrays: *edges*, *pointers* and *contents* are created without problems. But when it comes to *weights* creation, it throws exception with no informations. The exception occurs in newaop.cpp(not a my project file):

```
// newaop -- operator new[](size_t) REPLACEABLE
#include <new>

void *__CRTDECL operator new[](size_t count) _THROW1(std::bad_alloc)
    {   // try to allocate count bytes for an array
    return (operator new(count));
    }

/*
 * Copyright (c) 1992-2007 by P.J. Plauger.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
 * Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
 V5.03:0009 */
```

I have no idea what is going wrong. What is interesting if i replace other.vertexQty(399) with smaller number. For example:

```
        this->weights = new NodeWeight[10];
```

The exception isn't thrown. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please include the value of `other.vertexQty` at the moment of the exception?

Comment: Please include the `sizeof` `NodeWeight` at the momement of the exception.

Comment: Why are you using built-in arrays  and `new` in the first place? Anyway, try posting an MCVE.

Comment: int n, m; n = other.vertexQty; m = sizeof(new NodeWeight); //n = 399; m = 4

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
   this->contents = new int[other.vertexQty]();
```

You have an extra "()" at the end.
Since the function:

```
   new[](size_t)
```

requires a bytesize and your not passing it, it either throws an exception or allocates memory with an unknown size, hence the following creation works with a small number.

I suppose removing it should work.

Comment: It doesn't help but thank you for pointing it out. Probably you saved me from more strange problems.